# Calculate the limit of an integration domain

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the set $D(\varepsilon)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0<x^2+y^2\leq\varepsilon^2\}$, which is the filled disk of radius $\varepsilon$ with a hole at the origin. Calculate the limit

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D(\varepsilon)}\dfrac{1+\sin x+\sin y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}d(x,y).$$

My first instinct was to do a change of variables into polar coordinates which would give $D(\varepsilon)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0<r^2\leq\varepsilon^2; 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\}$ and

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D(\varepsilon)}[1+\sin(r\cos\theta)+\sin(r\sin\theta)]d(r,\theta),$$

But this does need seem any simpler than before. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: @RRL Doesn't this only provide an upper bound for the limit? Is there an analogous way of finding a lower bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ are odd functions and given the shape of the domain integrate to $0$ by symmetry. This means the limit equals

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\epsilon} drd\theta = 2\pi$$

Comment: Could you give a more specific explanation on how these odd functions integrate to zero over the given domain?

Comment: @TheHunter The domain has both an $x$ and a $y$ symmetry i.e. $0<(-x)^2 +y^2 \leq \epsilon^2 \iff 0<x^2+y^2\leq \epsilon^2$ and same for $y$. Under the interchanges $x\leftrightarrow -x$ and $y \leftrightarrow -y$ you will get the integral $I$ satisfies $I=-I$

Comment: Okay,  this helped me find it, thanks

Comment: @NinadMunshi looks like you split the original integral into three: $$\iint_{D(\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy + \iint_D(\varepsilon) + \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy + \iint_D(\varepsilon) + \frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy $$ Now your answer is more explicit and we see that the last integrals are zero, meaning that the initial integral equals to the 1st one of them. Then you both used polar coordinates, that is why I see no Jacobian here, it vanishes. That is the idea :)